# SonarQube : NoSuchMethodError Surefire plugin

Tags: maven, sonarqube, surefire, nosuchmethoderror

When I add the plugin **sonar-surefire-plugin** in my **sonar** (sonar v4.5.1 / surefire v3.3), when I run an analysis, I get the following error :

```
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.5:sonar (default-cli) on project XXXXXXX: org.sonar.plugins.surefire.api.SurefireUtils.getReportsDirectory(Lorg/sonar/api/config/Settings;Lorg/sonar/api/resources/Project;)Ljava/io/File;
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:355)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:160)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.sonar.plugins.surefire.api.SurefireUtils.getReportsDirectory(Lorg/sonar/api/config/Settings;Lorg/sonar/api/resources/Project;)Ljava/io/File;
    ... 22 more
```

Do you know why ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

As you can see on the [Java Plugin page](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Java+Plugin) (in the warning box), the Surefire plugin has been merged into the Java plugin so just remove it from your SonarQube instance.

Comment: It would be helpful to include this information on a page for the sonar-surefire-plugin on the documentation page. Linked from the http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Deprecated+Plugins page, too?